# В админке wordpress нету некоторых пунктов

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 4.7.5
Сижу через суперадмина, но нету таких пунктов меню как "Плагины" "Инструменты" "Настройки". Сайт не я разрабатывал поэтому даже незнаю, через бд поменял пароли на главного пользователя и зашел, та же история.
Как поставить обратно эти пункты меню?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался куда проще в function.php просто убрали пункты меню, закомментировал их и появились.

Кому надо

```
/* function remove_menus(){
    global $menu;
    $restricted = array(
        __('Dashboard'),
        __('Links'),
        __('Pages'),
        __('Appearance'),
        __('Tools'),
        __('Settings'),
        __('Comments'),
        __('Plugins')
    );
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu)){
        $value = explode(' ', $menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if( in_array( ($value[0] != NULL ? $value[0] : "") , $restricted ) ){
            unset($menu[key($menu)]);
        }
    }
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

> Сижу через суперадмина,

Это только так кажется :) Более того, [супер админ](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Super_Admin) есть только в сетевой установке. У обычного сайта - админ (administrator).

См в `wp_usermeta` у админа в поле `meta_value` будет запись вида `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`.

А плагины можно отключить переименовав их каталоги по ФТП. Так же по ФТП можно посмотреть `functions.php` активной темы. Это на случай, если вдруг действительно в базе админ, но вряд ли кто-то это программно отключал. Хотя такая возможность не исключается.

Comment: ну как бы я пытался высказаться как можно проще, а так конечно через бд смотрел

Comment: Ситуации, когда человек думает, что он админ, а по факту таковым не является - [нередки](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c/). Определить реального админа можно только по той записи, что я написал. А вот программное отключение я не встречал несколько лет. :)